# KeyBinding incrementing its command calls

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

So my app is basically a shell with a `ContentControl` that I populate with custom `UserControl`'s depending on the user selection of a menu.

But now I'm having a weird behaviour.

I had attached the `Content` property of the `ContentControl` to a ViewModel property wich I instantiate on demand. That works great but I'm having two problems.

1. When I select one option of the menu it creates a new instance of the specified `UserControl` and set the `Content` property the shell. That works, cause I see the control and can interact with it, and when I select another option from the menu, it shows me the other `UserControl`, but, when I select again the previosly selected option it seems to be loading the same previously instantiated control (the right one but with the older input, and I'm doing a new XXXControl() before setting it as the `Content` property of the `ContentControl`.
2. I'm calling a ShowDialog() from inside the custom control via Commands (from the user control view model I call the view via MVVM Light messaging and then show the dialog), and that works. But when I try to close the dialog it show it again the same number of time I select different options from the menu.

For example, I start with A menu and show the dialog, then the close button works, then I goes to B menu and back to A, then the close button works at the second press (two ShowDialog() are being called) and so on...

I don't know wich part of the code must I paste in order to give a little more of context to this post, but any input will be appreciated. I'm stuck with this (mine) bug.

**Code**

On the shell view:

```
<ContentControl Grid.Row="2" Content="{Binding CurrentView}" Margin="15,10"/>
```

On the shell ViewModel:

```
if (action == null || action == SEARCH_ACTION)
    {
        ActionsMenuSelected = SEARCH_ACTION;
        var view = new SearchDocumentView();
        CurrentView = view;
    }
```

On the inner view (SearchDocumentView):

```
public SearchDocumentView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage<Entity>>(this, NotificationMessageReceived);
}


private void NotificationMessageReceived(NotificationMessage<Entity> msg)
{
    if (msg.Notification == "ViewResult")
    {
        var view = new DocumentViewer( ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IDataService>(),msg.Content);
        view.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

On the inner view (SearchDocumentView) xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="SearchResults"  ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResults}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSearchResult}">
            <ListBox.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding
                            Key="Enter"
                            Command="{Binding ViewResult}" />
                <KeyBinding
                            Key="Return"
                            Command="{Binding ViewResult}" />
            </ListBox.InputBindings>
            ...
```

On the inner view (SearchDocumentView) ViewModel:

```
private RelayCommand _viewResut;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the ViewResult.
        /// </summary>
        public RelayCommand ViewResult
        {
            get
            {
                return _viewResut
                    ?? (_viewResut = new RelayCommand(
                                          () =>
                                          {
                                              MessengerInstance.Send(new NotificationMessage<Entity>((Entity)SelectedSearchResult, "ViewResult"));
                                          },
                                          () => ((Entity)SelectedSearchResult!=null)?true:false ));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Paste the xaml code where you set the content and the code where you are instantiating the usercontrols. Also the code snippet where you are calling ShowDialog().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you see your old data I cannot see right now - but I guess you use the same (model)-data for the newly created view.

The second problem should be here:

```
public SearchDocumentView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage<Entity>>(this, NotificationMessageReceived);
}
```

For each new view your register a Notification, that will show your message box but I don't see if you unregister those and if you don't the handler will hold the viewmodel in memory and will still show the messages boxes.

Even if I got it wrong (is this your "controls"-viewmodel?) it should be something very similar, but you can find this easily by setting a breakpoint to the `.Show` on your message and looking at the callstack while debugging.

Comment: Thank you @Carsten, actually you're right. I was using the IoC container to resolve the ViewModel and so then using the same instance. Now, for the second problem I don't know exactly how to unregister the view (don't see how unregistering the viewmodel could help), can you be a little more detailed on that, thanks.

Comment: Hi, as far as I can remember (don't have code here) there should be a `Unregister` method on the `IMessenger`(?) interface (so also on the `Messenger.Default` expecting the recipent (so call it with `Messenger.Default.Unregister(this);` in your view) - se here: http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/09/27/mvvm-light-toolkit-messenger-v2-beta.aspx

Comment: Remark: the blog-entry says that MVVM-light uses weak-references so the number of "messages" you see should decrease with time, just as a side node ;)